# Is it correct to use the Uri class to manipulate folders?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is correct to use the Uri class to create local path like "C:/my folder/my subfolder" ?

I ask this question because when I manipulate Uri I get some errors.

```
string foo = new Uri(uri1, uri2).AbsolutePath;
```

The AbsolutePath return my absolute path but replace all space with %20. What should I do? I see two solutions

1. stop using Uri and replace it with the correct class.
2. replace all %20 with space. I dont't like this one

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just combine 2 file paths? You may want to use `Path.Combine` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Path class.

```
Path.Combine(@"C:\my folder", "my subfolder");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [System.IO.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class for that, see the link for additional information and examples.

Comment: Why not put the information and examples in the answer directly, instead of making a link-only answer?

Comment: That is a fair point, but the question gave me the impression that a concise example would not have been as useful as a broader exposure to the (hopefully) appropriate class.